# iPhone tethering not working on Windows 10 (iOS 15.5)

Tags: windows, networking, iphone, ios, tethering

I switched to the iPhone 13 Pro Max about a month or so ago, but the USB tethering has never worked. It's really sad to see, because USB tethering is basically the main source of my internet. It does work with a wireless hotspot, but it's far less reliable and it's also slower than the tethered connection. Since I plan on mainly using it for gaming, this really isn't an option for me.

Here's a list of what I've tried so far:

- Reset the iPhone.
- Reset the Network Settings of the iPhone.
- Reset network settings on the PC.

I've also tried executing `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew`.

However, when trying to renew I get the following message written in the console:

> An error occurred while renewing interface iPhone : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this? Because it's been quite a hassle thusfar. I'm actually pretty surprised that such a simple feature isn't even working properly.

---

**Edit**: I'm also quite sure that my Phone is connected properly, it only show that there's no internet. (Sometimes it does say it's connected but it still isn't connected to the internet)
[image: Phone connected, no internet]

Comment: I have no experience with iPhone tethering with USB myself, but most sources point out that you need to have iTunes installed (or at least the drivers that come with it) to make this work.

Comment: I am not certain. I no longer have Windows 10. I tethered my new iPhone 13 (iPhone SE prior) to my Windows 11 Pro computer and it works just fine. Try doing DISM/SFC on Windows 10. (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: @StarCat I already have iTunes installed, should’ve mentioned it in my question. But I thought it was quite obvious as the iPhone was seen as an Ethernet source

Comment: To my knowledge iPhones do not support USB tethering.  *EVERY* article on the subject, instructs the user to use Hotspot tethering, I suspect that is the entire  problem.  Your screenshots clearly indicated that while connect to your phone you don't have an IP address assigned to your device and thus is the reason you have no internet connectivity.

Comment: @Ramhound on Apple’s official website however, they state that you can connect your hotspot through a USB cable. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph45447ca6/ios . Maybe in the end, we do mean the same thing, but on my Samsung it was called USB tethering.

Comment: I did this both Hotspot and USB on Windows 11 Pro and it worked. I no longer have Windows 10 except VM.

Comment: @John Ah ok.. So it’s probably also a W10 problem. I’ll try the solution you provided first and if it doesn’t work then maybe I have to go through the trouble of getting my PC ready for Windows 11.

Comment: I am not sure, but for certain, I used an iPhone SE IOS 14 thereabouts tethered by USB to Windows 10.  New iPhone only on Windows 11.

Comment: @K.Koster - Are you getting the prompt to trust the machine on the iPhone?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I do, I always click trust. Still doesn’t give me internet access. It does sometimes connect however, but still without an actual internet connection.

Comment: Your mobile phone provider doesn’t otherwise limit tethering mode do they?

Comment: @Ramhound No they don’t, because I’ve had the exact same SIM card and provider as I had in my Samsung.

Comment: @John Still had no luck with the method you provided, unfortunately

Comment: See https://bartsimons.me/getting-iphone-usb-tethering-on-windows-without-itunes/

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue this morning. I had a network outage and tried to connect my PC to the Internet through iPhone.

My phone is iPhone 11 pro max and PC runs Windows 11 pro (latest). The desktop PC has no WiFi capabilities.

When I enabled iPhone "Network sharing" and connected iPhone through USB, no Internet connection turned up. There was no exclamation mark reported in my device manager on iPhone and "Update driver" did nothing.

I figured it out that Windows must have iTunes installed to get USB tethering to work. Even though Windows believed it had the driver for iPhone, it was not the right one. iTunes is a must.

I then downloaded the latest iTunes through my phone and transferred it to my PC through LAN FTP. Then the USB tethering worked straightaway. Now I am posting this answer using the same iPhone USB tethering network.